# Switch Content of a specific part on screen in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, ios8

I have a view controller with a basic layout. It is part of a uinavigationcontroller. I have a title and two buttons on top of the screen. The part underneath the buttons should be dynamically. I already tried a solution with just using two view controller with the same layout and using a normal segue. But i want a solution where the buttons on top and the title are fixed.

With the segue you see them moving...Is there may be the possibility to do it with uicontainer view?!

Comment: How complex is the UI? Do you need a separate view controller for that? Cant you just put that in a view and control it from the same view controller?

Comment: I think i could do that too. And than just switch the views with setHidden:YES / NO?!

Comment: yeah. if its a simple UI, do that. Instead of hiding, add and remove from the view.

Comment: Ahh okay...Yes its simple UI...So i can design two UIViews in Storyboard and then just add or remove it!?

Comment: Storyboards are mainly used for view controllers. Use a XIB to design views.